# CSS Button Generator code does not apply the effects to the html file

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to create a "button" that when a user clicks on it, it will open their email inbox to send me a direct email. I used https://cssbuttoncreator.com/ to style my button, and I checked the codes and everything seemed fine. However, when I pasted the codes into my css file and re-run my website, nothing happened to the button.

**html file**

```html
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Calum Nguyen</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&family=Montserrat&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <a class="btn" href="mailto:nguy127@usc.edu">CONTACT ME</a>
```

**css file**

```css
    btn {
      background: #11CDD4;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11CDD4, #11999E);
      -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius: 8px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 100;
      padding: 40px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
      -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #000000;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .btn:hover {
      border: solid #DD380D 1px;
      background: #30E3CB;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
      -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running your code by copying the HTML code in file "media.html" and CSS code in "media.css" which is in css folder and file and folder are in a folder named "ES5Learning". I am getting the expected result.Please have a look at how I have placed the files. Below is the code I tried and screenshots that it is working:-

HTML code in media.html file:-

```
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <title>Calum Nguyen</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
           <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
           <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
          family=Merriweather&family=Montserrat&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>




<a class="btn" href="mailto:nguy127@usc.edu">CONTACT ME</a>

</html>
```

This is CSS code in media.css file:-

```
.btn {
    background: #11CDD4;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #000000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn:hover {
border: solid #DD380D 1px;
background: #30E3CB;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30E3CB, #2BC4AD);
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

These are screenshots of running code:-
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I use Atom to edit my codes on my Mac. Would there be a possibility that that could be a reason why the codes did not work on my computer?

Comment: That must not affect the output of the code if it is correct. Try to install "Visual Studio Code Insiders" and run the code there. Let me know if that makes any difference.